# Hide foldcolumn when no folds?

Tags: folding

Currently I have `set foldcolumn=1`, but in a buffer with no folds, it's just a waste of space.

Is there a convenient event to listen to in order to automatically toggle it between `0` and `1` (or whatever preference for 'on')?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such event.

I opened [an issue on vim’s github](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1866) about getting an `auto` value acceptable for the `'foldcolumn'` option, but I don’t recall it gaining any traction.

I developed [Auto Origami](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami) for just this purpose.